# Inherit view from base view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In a project I'm working on, I have the need of a base UI. So i made a baseViewController, made the view in a xib-file and set the baseViewController's view to be the view in the xib-file.

Then I want to inherit that view from the xib-file to my other controllers, but it does not work. Is this impossible? Or have I just missed something?

Comment: What do mean 'inherit'? Do you just mean use it? If you mean inherit, you can subclass your view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a container view controller with a nib, and then adding all other view controllers as child view controllers when it was needed, and removing them when I was done with them. See this tutorial: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/

Answer (score 0):

```
Example:

//common
 playagain = [[game alloc] initWithNibName:@"game" bundle:nil];

//depends on what you use
[[self view] addSubview: [playagain view]];
```

Use this in other controllers and make sure you import the controller in other controllers... The function is initWithNibName where your nibName goes in.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to write any code to set the view in the children of baseViewController. I have now just written initWithNibName:@"OUSBaseViewController", and it works (your example gave me the idea), but I didn't want to write any code, just connect the view in the xib-file with my baseController, but that doesn't work. Oh well.

Comment: without having any code, how do u pass the control over to the next controller?

Comment: I was hoping the child would automatically inherit the parents UI, which I made in a xib. But it seem like I have to specify the nib each time explicitly in the baseController, or else the children won't get it. If you understod that, not the best explenation.

Comment: Class names should start with a capital letter. View controllers should have 'ViewController' as part of their name.

Comment: Also, if your nib file has the same name as the view controller, you don't need to specify the nib name using initWithNibName. Just using init will work because init for UIViewController automatically looks for a nib with the same name.